# libimobiledevice: Get off from restore mode iPad

Tags: 16.04, ipad

I successfully entered the recovery mode on my device using: `ideviceenterrecovery -d MY_UDID_NUMBER`
By using `idevicepair list` I can retrieve my UDID, so the device is recognized.

**How to get off from restore mode from my iPad?**

```
lsusb: Bus 001 Device 010: ID 05ac:1281 Apple, Inc. Apple Mobile Device [Recovery Mode]
```

I used `ibimobiledevice-dev` from 16.04 packages ([launchpad.net - Ubuntu Xenial libimobiledevice](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/libimobiledevice))

Comment: Maybe you need to use 'sudo ideviceenterrecovery -d MY_UDID_NUMBER' ?

Comment: No results. Ideviceenterrecovery just has these options:
'ideviceenterrecovery [OPTIONS] UDID
Makes a device with the supplied 40-digit UDID enter recovery mode immediately.

  -d, --debug  enable communication debugging
  -h, --help  prints usage information

Homepage: <http://libimobiledevice.org>